# Git Submodules stuck in "Changes"

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

Source Control of VScode shows changes with submodule file names in root project i can't stage them and i can't remove them no errors in console.

Demo:
https://streamable.com/lyrz4p

Comment: what happens if you right-click on Changes? Does it give you any options?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you would need to go in one of those ("M") modified submodule folder, add and commit there.

Back on the main repository, you should be able to add and commit the submodule folder.

Rinse and repeat for other "modules" in your repository.